# PowerPoint Slide Zoom Hide Objects

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

The slide into which I'm zooming contains several animated objects. How can I hide these objects in the Slide Zoom preview?

The slide contains a lot of objects and text in its final state and looks cluttered if shown all at once. It's especially nonsensical if it's 10 times smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem is easily solved by using the **Change Image** function of the slide zoom.

1. Click on the slide zoom object
2. In the ribbon, click on the **Format** tab
3. On the left, click on the **Change Image** button

[image]

Comment: Using Change Image here would require that you have a screenshot of the slide without all of the animated objects, correct? So you would need to view the slide, save a screenshot to file, then use Change Image to select that screenshot to use for each affected Slide Zoom?